# Unable to start STS3 Eclipse under macOS High Sierra

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am unable to start the STS3 Eclipse IDE. I am using macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6. and STS version 3.9.6.201809180749-RELEASE-e49. The startup fails with SIGSEV.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

Full error trace can be seen here:
https://pastebin.com/5gQ9e1Jt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the STS process crashes when looking up the JVM or starting the JVM (just a wild guess here). I would try to solve this my downloading a recent JDK 1.8 from Oracle and specify that JVM in the `STS.ini` file, like you would do in the `eclipse.ini` for a regular Eclipse installation (as described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).